# Modx chunk as tpl returns php array in pre tags

Tags: php, modx, modx-templates, modx-resources

I have a problem regarding showing the contents of template file.

My actual code to get this template is:

```
[[!getPage? &element=`getResources`
            &tpl=`individual-productswebspec`
            &sortby=`menuindex`
            &sortdir=`ASC`
            &includeContent=`1`
            &includeTVs=`1`
            &limit=`[[!sortValue]]`
]]
```

Where `individual-productswebspec` is my file which I want to show contents in `&tpl=` variable and it is stored in `chunks` folder.

My another page is showing this same content fine without any error but when i show this `&tpl=individual-productswebspec` on anther page say `abc` it shows PHP array in the `<pre>` tags.

My whole data is loaded to this `<pre>` tags. And no proper output is render on the page.

Answer (score 0):

When getResources does not have a tpl attribute or cannot find the chunk specified in tpl, it will just dump the results array in a set of  tags. I suspect that on your non-working pages that you have individual-productswebspec misspelled. [check: case? extra spaces? missing back ticks?]